# C++, OpenGL - Rendering large amount of... teapots

Tags: c++, opengl

I am quite new in OpenGL programming. My goal was to set object-oriented graphics programming and I proudly can say that I done some progress. Now I have different problem.

Lets say we have working program what can make one, two or many rotating teapots. I made this by using list inside my class. Raw code for Drawing function is here:

```
void Draw(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();

for(list<teapot>::iterator it=teapots.begin();it!=teapots.end();it++){
glTranslatef(it->pos.x,it->pos.y,it->pos.z);
glRotatef(angle,it->ang.x,it->ang.y,it->ang.z);
glutSolidTeapot(it->size);
glRotatef(angle,-it->ang.x,-it->ang.y,-it->ang.z);
glTranslatef(-it->pos.x,-it->pos.y,-it->pos.z);
}
glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Everything is great, but when I draw large amount of teapots - say, 128 in two rows - my fps number drops. I don't know, if it is just hardware limit or I make something wrong? Maybe glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() should happen more often? Or less often?

Comment: GLUT uses immediate mode rendering, which is awful for performance. Use VBOs instead, or at least render the teapot to a display list first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using an old, deprecated part of OpenGL (called "immediate mode") in which all the graphics data is sent from the CPU to the GPU every frame:  inside `glutSolidTeapot()` is code that does something like `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)` followed by lots of `glVertex3f(...)` and finally `glEnd()`.  The reason that's deprecated is because it's a bottleneck.  GPUs are highly parallel and are capable of processing many triangles at the same time, but they can't do that if your program is sending the vertices one-at-a-time with `glVertex3f`.

You should learn about the modern OpenGL API, in which you start by creating a "buffer object" and loading your vertex data into it — basically uploading your shape into the GPU's memory *once*, up-front — and then you can issue lots of calls telling the GPU to draw triangles using the vertices in that buffer object, instead of having to send all the vertices again every time.

(Unfortunately, this means you won't be able to use `glutSolidTeapot()`, since that draws in immediate mode and doesn't know how to produce vertex data for a buffer object.  But I'm sure you can find a teapot model somewhere on the web.)

[Open.gl](https://open.gl/) is a decent tutorial that I know of for modern-style OpenGL, but I'm sure there are others as well.

Comment: +1 because I like teapots. And partly because what you wrote is correct.

Comment: Thanks man! Now I understand that generating a teapot is not very good start... ;)

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with rendering a teapot as a test.  Just put it in a VBO instead of using `glutSolidTeapot` to draw it in immediate mode.

Answer (score 1):

Wyzard is right,partially.Besides the fact you are using old deprecated API where on each draw call you submit all your data again and again from CPU to GPU you also expect to maintain descent frame rate while rendering the same geometry multiple times.So in fact,keeping such an approach to geometry rendering while using programmable pipeline will not gain you much either.You will start noticing FPS drop already after +- 40-60 objects(depends on your GPU).What you really need is called batched drawing.The batch drawing may have different techniques all of witch imply you using  modern OpenGL as we are talking here of data buffers(Arrays of vertices in your case which you upload to GPU).You can either push all the geometry into a single vertex buffer or use [instanced rendering](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial33/tutorial33.html) commands.In your case ,if all you are after is drawing the same mesh multiple times,second technique is perfect solution.There are more complex techniques like [indirect multiple draw](http://www.openglsuperbible.com/2013/10/16/the-road-to-one-million-draws/) commands ,which allow you drawing indeed very large quantities of different geometry by a single draw call.But those are pretty advanced for the beginners.Anyway,the bottom line is you must  move to modern OpenGL and start using geometry batching if you want to keep your app FPS high while drawing large amounts of meshes.